# Can I make the shift+right-click the default right-click action on tasks in the task menu?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

When I right click on a running task in my start menu I usually get 3 options:

- Launch a new copy of this - I don't use this
- Pin this program to the taskbar - I don't use this
- Close window - I use this. Lots. So much so that in Windows XP I used to right click and press 'c'. Which I can no longer do because while it hilights the close MenuItem, it doesn't actually invoke it.

If I shift+right-click on the task, I get the old menu upon which I can just hit C. This old menu is also generally much more useful as it has many more options I use considerably more frequently.

Is there a way I can make this menu pop up as the default right-click menu?

This is also proving to be a real pain to google. As I'm always up for improving my goo-fu, if you do google a fix to this problem I would appreciate it if you could share the keywords/phrases used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use AutoHotKey for this:

```
RButton::RButton
RButton UP:: ;To auto-ctrl-shift-click on taskbar items
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseGetPos, x, y, WinUnderMouseID
yBottom := A_ScreenHeight - y
if yBottom <= 40
{
Send ^+{RButton}
}
else
if GetKeyState("RButton")==1
send {RButton UP}
else
send {RButton}
return
```

Simply insert that into (Your script | A blank Script), or use [this compiled version](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2502059/Autohotkey%20Scripts/ShiftClickStartmenu.exe), and it should function fine.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in these posts ( http://www.intowindows.com/tweak-windows-7-taskbar-with-7-taskbar-tweaker/, http://lifehacker.com/5397963/7-taskbar-tweaker-brings-fine+grained-control-to-windows-7s-taskbar) it is also possible to use [7 Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed Phoshi's code a little bit. You should be able to drag right click and drag highlight now. It also closes the program on the taskbar with just right click without needing you you to press c. If you have the "use small icons" box checked then change "yBottom <= 40" to "yBottom <= 30".

```
; Right Click program on taskbar -> Shift Right Click + C
RButton::
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseGetPos, x, y, WinUnderMouseID
    yBottom := A_ScreenHeight - y
    xRight := A_ScreenWidth - x
    if (yBottom <= 40 && x >= 58 && xRight >= 223)
    {
        Send ^+{RButton}
        Send c
    }
    else
    {
        Send {RButton down}
        KeyWait, RButton
        Send {RButton up}
    }
return
```